# Is there a way to create animation from array of 2d sprites in runtime that works in build in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I have an array of sprites that is created at runtime and I would like to create animation from it, so the specific animation would also exist at runtime only it would act as preview animation.

I tried something like this:

```
public void CreateAnimation()
{
    Sprite[] sprites = createSprite();

    AnimationClip animClip = new AnimationClip();
 
    AnimationClipSettings newSettings = new AnimationClipSettings();
    newSettings.loopTime = true;
    AnimationUtility.SetAnimationClipSettings(animClip, newSettings);
 
    EditorCurveBinding spriteBinding = EditorCurveBinding.PPtrCurve("", typeof(SpriteRenderer), "m_sprite");

    float interval = 1 / 4f;
    ObjectReferenceKeyframe[] spriteKeyFrames = new ObjectReferenceKeyframe[sprites.Length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < spriteKeyFrames.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i == spriteKeyFrames.Length - 1)
        {
            spriteKeyFrames[i].time = i * interval;
            spriteKeyFrames[i].value = sprites[0];
        }
        else
        {
            spriteKeyFrames[i].time = i * interval;
            spriteKeyFrames[i].value = sprites[i];
        }
    }

    AnimationUtility.SetObjectReferenceCurve(animClip, spriteBinding, spriteKeyFrames);

    AnimatorOverrideController animatorOverrideController = new AnimatorOverrideController();
    animatorOverrideController.runtimeAnimatorController = animC.runtimeAnimatorController;
    animatorOverrideController["TestAnim"] = animClip;
    animC.runtimeAnimatorController = animatorOverrideController;

}
```

Inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HEAUZa-ZBM)
and [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1080430/create-animation-clip-from-sprites-programmaticall.html).

I managed to create animation clip but I can't play the animation and even if I did what I understand by other comments and posts this method would not work in build because it uses the `UnityEditor` namespace.

So now I am not sure if there is any way of creating this kind of animation at runtime that also works in build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not just use coroutine:

```
IEnumerator doAnimation()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < spritearray.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.03F);
        myImage.sprite = spritearray[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: Would this have big impact on performance with lager number of sprites?

Comment: As compared to what?

Comment: compared to standard animation

Comment: I don't know. My simple guess would be 'no', it should not make any noticeable difference 'in most cases'. Why should it - in both cases images are loaded in to memory and rendered on screen. But who knows maybe 'standard animation' use some clever video encoding, maybe not. To get real answer you'd have to make benchmarks yourself to see which method is more efficient. And if that difference in efficiency is relevant at all.

Comment: but what this code does is display 1 picture at a time.  The rest is being held in array. So basically you are asking 'I have lots of pics in array - are arrays efficient??'. And yes, arrays are efficient. But if you have really really big array you would see drop in performance (I guess :) )

Comment: Makes sense thanks for the answer I cant belive I missed it :).